# Model abstract classes in a hierarchical order

Tags: c#

I have some abstract classes representing ice cream menu items. I want them to be hierarchical, meaning:

- Basic: Sprinkles
- Gourmet: Whipped cream, and everything from Basic (sprinkles)
- Deluxe: Caramel, and everything from Gourmet (whipped cream and sprinkles)

Below are the three classes. What is the best way, aside from explicitly adding the toppings from the other classes, to link the classes together such that Deluxe contains everything from Gourmet and Basic, and Gourmet contains everything from Basic? In a single class, I would just chain the constructors.

```
public abstract class Basic : IceCream
{
    public Basic() : base("Basic")
    {
        _toppings.Add("Sprinkles");
    }
}

public abstract class Gourmet : IceCream
{
    public Gourmet() : base("Gourmet")
    {
        _toppings.Add("Whipped Cream"));
    }
}

public abstract class Deluxe : IceCream
{
    public Deluxe() : base("Deluxe")
    {
        _toppings.Add("Caramel"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are modelling the construction of an ice-cream, so I would use composition, rather than inheritance.

Comment: Here's why it's an issue, if you start with an instance of `basic` (as per your existing model), because the customer says they just wanted sprinkles, but then at the last minute they said that they wanted caramel, then you have to change the type of the instance at run-time. You can't do that with the inheritance model. Bu with composition you just add the caramel and you're done.

Comment: Can you please post the class definition for `IceCream`?

Answer (score 1):

As per my comments on the question, you should think about using composition rather than inheritance.

If you start with an instance of `Basic` (as per your existing model), because the customer says they just wanted sprinkles, but then at the last minute they said that they wanted caramel, then you have to change the type of the instance at run-time. You can't do that with the inheritance model. But with composition you just add the caramel and you're done.

Start with a definition for `Topping` and `ToppingLevel`:

```
public enum ToppingLevel
{
    Basic,
    Gourmet,
    Deluxe,
}

public class Topping
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public ToppingLevel Level { get; private set; }

    public Topping(string name, ToppingLevel level)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Level = level;
    }
}
```

Now it's easy to create toppings:

```
var sprinkles = new Topping("Sprinkles", ToppingLevel.Basic);
var whipped_cream = new Topping("Whipped Cream", ToppingLevel.Gourmet);
var caramel = new Topping("Caramel", ToppingLevel.Deluxe);
```

Then we just need one definition for `IceCream`:

```
public class IceCream
{
    private List<Topping> _toppings = new List<Topping>();
    public void AddTopping(Topping topping)
    {
        _toppings.Add(topping);
    }
    public IEnumerable<Topping> Toppings { get => _toppings.ToArray(); }
    public ToppingLevel Level
    {
        get =>
            _toppings
                .OrderByDescending(x => (int)x.Level)
                .FirstOrDefault()?.Level ?? ToppingLevel.Basic;
    }
}
```

Now I can write this:

```
var icecream = new IceCream();
Console.WriteLine(icecream.Level);

icecream.AddTopping(sprinkles);
Console.WriteLine(icecream.Level);

icecream.AddTopping(whipped_cream);
Console.WriteLine(icecream.Level);

icecream.AddTopping(caramel);
Console.WriteLine(icecream.Level);
```

That outputs:

```
Basic
Basic
Gourmet
Deluxe
```

You can see that by simply adding a topping I've changed the "Level" of the ice-cream without needing to change its `Type` at run-time.